# Specializing std::hash for templated Key

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, hash, stdhash

I was trying to specialize hash for my own type, a templated key.

I was basing it off [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

I get the compile error "The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type". I figure I just did it wrong. Could the compiler even support this kind of template?

```
namespace std {
    template<typename SType, typename AType, typename PType>
    struct MyKey {
        const SType from;
        const AType consume;
        const PType pop;
    };

    template<typename SType, typename AType, typename PType>
    struct hash<MyKey<SType, AType, PType>> {
        size_t operator ()(MyKey const &key) {
            std::hash<SType>()(key.from);
            std::hash<AType>()(key.consume);
            std::hash<PType>()(key.pop);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You have to teach the compiler how to hash your types - not just `MyKey`, but `SType`. `AType` and `PType` too (at least those that're not `typedef`s for known types).  After you've done that, `MyKey`'s hash shouldn't just call the member variable's hash functions, it should return a `hash_combine`d value incorporating those member variables' hashes.  There are ***lots*** of existing questions explaining this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

You are not allowed to place new definitions or declarations into the `std` namespace; only specializations (such as `std::hash`) are allowed. So your `MyKey` template should be moved out of the `std` namespace.

Your `operator()` signature is incorrect. `MyKey` doesn't name a type, you need to explicitly paramaterise it. Additionally, the operator should be marked `const`.

`std::hash` specializations should provide the member types `argument_type` and `result_type`.

If there are not existing specializations for the types passed in as `SType` etc., you need to provide them yourself.

You are not returning anything from your hash function, just computing the hashes of the other types and throwing their return values away.

An implementation which will compile for types which have their own `std::hash` specialization:

```
//moved out of std
template<typename SType, typename AType, typename PType>
struct MyKey {
    const SType from;
    const AType consume;
    const PType pop;
};

namespace std {
    template<typename SType, typename AType, typename PType>
    struct hash<MyKey<SType, AType, PType>>{
        //member types
        using argument_type = MyKey<SType,AType,PType>;
        //arguments specified         ^     ^     ^
        using result_type = std::size_t;

        result_type operator ()(argument_type const& key) const {
        //marked const                                      ^
            //these will fail if SType and friends don't have a std::hash specialization
            result_type s_hash = std::hash<SType>()(key.from);
            result_type a_hash = std::hash<AType>()(key.consume);
            result_type p_hash = std::hash<PType>()(key.pop);

            //in your actual code, you'll want to compute the return type from the above
            return p_hash;
        }
    };
}
```